# Об употреблении слов "только", "либо", "или"

Tags: семантика

Предположим, что на столике лежат туз, король, дама и валет.

Верно ли, что указание "Возьми либо туза, либо короля, либо даму, либо валета." означает указание "Возьми либо только туза, либо только короля, или возьми либо только даму, либо только валета."?

P.S. Дорогие филологи, поправьте меня, если я неправильно расставил знаки пунктуации.

Answer (score 1):

Знаки препинания расставлены верно.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.