# Об употреблении слов "должен" и "либо"

Tags: семантика

Предположим, что на столике лежат туз, король, дама и валет.

Верно ли, что:

- указание "Возьми туза." ("Take the ace.") означаете приказание "Ты должен взять туза." ("You must take the ace."),
- указание "Не бери туза." ("Don't take the ace.") означает приказание "Тебе нельзя брать туза." ("You mustn't take the ace."),
- указание "Либо возьми туза, либо не бери туза." ("Either take the ace, or don't take the ace.") означает "Либо ты должен взять туза, либо тебе нельзя брать туза." ("Either you must take the ace, or you mustn't take the ace.")?

P.S. Настоящий вопрос сформулирован под впечатлением от ответа участника Серж.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Об употреблении слов "только", "либо", "или"](http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/35988/%d0%9e%d0%b1-%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8)

Answer (score 1):

В приведенных вами примерах повелительное наклонение. Выбор того или иного значения обусловлен ситуацией.

Comment: Чем вызван перевод русского указания на английский? Тем ли, что в нашем форуме участвуют англичане? Или там, что автор вопроса хочет показать, что в совершенстве владеет английским языком? Думается, и в том, и в другом случае не мешало бы дать развёрнутый перевод вопроса на английский язык (А где "Спасибо за участие?" Кроме Сержа, меня и  Niemand-а (заочно!), никто не стал бы обсуждать столь сложный вопрос. Так что благодарите всех троих). P.S. Значит, сначала Серж ответил на вопрос, а уж потом Вы его сформулировали? Или P.S. появилось после ответа Сержа? Коллега, будьте логичнее, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

Неверно. Повелительное наклонение — это грамматическое "состояние" глагола, которое может выражать различные речевые намерения или *коммуникативные интенции* (в скобках предполагаемые контекст или интонация): 
1. *(Быстро) возьми туза* — приказ;
2. *(Пожалуйста) возьми туза* — просьба;
3. *(Да) возьми (уже) туза* — побуждение;
4. *Возьми туза (так будет лучше)* — совет.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос к семантике отношения не имеет и вообще - типичный троллинг. Даже если не вспоминать историю этого пользователя (который был способен задать десятки подобных вопросов, меняя одно-два слова в условии) вопрос сам по себе некорректен. Он требует строго решения в то время как метод его получения - чисто субъективный. Не решаются такие вещи опросами и голосованием.

Comment: Лучше заминусовать вопрос и запостить критику как комментарий. Тем более что минусовать вопросы можно без ущерба своему рейтингу ;)

Comment: Ну рейтинг-то мой все выдержит.... А чем так плохо? Я ведь дал ответ. В таких вопросах утверждение об отсутствии ответа - тоже ответ. Вон Серж то же самое сказал - лайк получил.